# Proving Properties of orthogonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

I was given a task whereby its defined that a $n \times n$ matrix, A, is orthogonal if $\langle A\vec{u},A\vec{v}\rangle$ = $\langle \vec{u}$,$\vec{v}\rangle$ and i have also been given the property that

$\langle A\vec{u},\vec{v}\rangle$ = $\langle \vec{u},A^T\vec{v}\rangle$ .

Now if $A$ is an orthogonal matrice how do i prove that $A^TA = I_n$

I know how to prove it using the property that an orthogonal matrices has column vectors that are orthonormal. However we were told to prove this property in the later part so I don't think we should use that in this question. So if not using this property, I'm completely lost in proving this and I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Given the two properties you can say that $<A^TA\overline{u},\overline{u}>=<A\overline{u},A\overline{u}>=<\overline{u},\overline{u}>$

Comment: **Hint:** Combining the two given properties we arrive to $\langle u,A^TAv\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is orthogonal, then, for any two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, you have $\left\langle A\vec u,A\vec v\right\rangle=\left\langle\vec u,\vec v\right\rangle$. But you also have $\left\langle A\vec u,A\vec v\right\rangle=\left\langle\vec u,A^\top A\vec v\right\rangle$. So, for any two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$,$$\left\langle\vec u,A^\top A\vec v\right\rangle=\left\langle\vec u,\vec v\right\rangle.$$In other words,$$\left\langle\vec u,\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v\right\rangle=0.$$In particular,$$\left\|\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v\right\|^2=\left\langle\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v,\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v\right\rangle=0.$$So, for every vector $\vec v$, $\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v=\vec0$; in other words, $A^\top A\vec v=\vec v$.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for this. However I'm quite lost at why you did the A^T.A-Id part then equating it to zero I'm quite lost after that. I'm sorry to be asking such a question as I'm still quite new to this and I'm trying to grasp the concept of all this.

Comment: Your aim is to prove that $A^\top A=\operatorname{Id}$. This is the same thing as asserting that $A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}=0$, which, in turn, means that, for every vector $\vec v$, $\left(A^\top A-\operatorname{Id}\right)\vec v=\vec0$.

Comment: so basically the first line itself kinda implies that A^T.A(v)=v so A^T.A is an identity matrix since when multiplied by v it gives us v back?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ahhh thank you so much!! this really helped

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

For some matrix $C$, we know that if $u^T C v = 0$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$, then $C = O$.
$$
\left<A u, Av\right>
=
u^T A^T A v = u^T v
$$
or
$$
u^T (A^T A - I) v = 0
$$
for all vectors $u$, $v$.